# No matching client found for package name 'io.ionic.starter'

Tags: cordova, angularfire, ionic4

I'm trying to emulate the application on my smartphone, but when I've tried to run the `ionic cordova run android` I got that error

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'io.ionic.starter'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova run android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I've been trying lots of thing, but anyone worked

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your using some google product,suspecting google-services with different id than your apps id or vice versa.

check for the file path as well for googles....its should be under src folder of that app

please check that case and try to import with the same id in both.